# Can you run a MOCA adapter / router on the same coax line?

Tags: ethernet, internet, network

I have my ISP gateway at the bottom of my home, service is delivered through coax. I have a coax wall jack upstairs as well.

I would like to install a MOCA adapter downstairs and one upstairs so I can get hardwired connection upstairs.

The problem, of course, is the modem needs the coax line as well. Is it ok to install a splitter on the downstairs coax line, one end goes to the modem, one end goes to the moca adapter? If not, im not sure how to navigate this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused. Where does service enter the home? If it is upstairs, move the gateway up. If it is downstairs then the modem isn't using the downstairs-upstairs coax. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I want the modem downstairs because I want to hard wire stuff, and I also want to hardwire stuff upstairs. The modem can be in either location, so there is a link. My main concern is running the modem and moca adapter on one coax line.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. **Where does the line enter the building from outside?**

Comment: From the demark box on the side of the house. There is a splitter in there. The in line comes from the utility pole and the out lines go into the home through multiple outlets.

Comment: What's left unsaid here is what the other cables are for. **It sounds like**: There are other coaxial cables that go to the upstairs from a split that is prior to the modem in order to provide TV signals? Is that correct? Because if not, I'm having trouble figuring out why there is any coax between the floors.